# REST and SOAP on Embedded Jetty, SOAP work alone but not if REST run

Tags: java, rest, soap

I have a embedded Jetty implementation. I can only run either REST or SOAP. As soon as I add the REST service my SOAP endpoints don't work. I have below code to setup the SOAP and then the REST service. The REST service always work.

Setup the Jetty server

```
 InetSocketAddress jettyAddress = new InetSocketAddress(tsConfig.getBindIp(), tsConfig.getPort());
        Server server = new Server(jettyAddress);
        server.setStopAtShutdown(true);

        JettyHttpServer jettyServer = new JettyHttpServer(server, true);
        final Executor executor = jettyServer.getExecutor();
        if(executor != null) {
            if (executor instanceof QueuedThreadPool) {
                ((QueuedThreadPool) executor).setName("td-jetty");
            } else {
                LOGGER.warn("Jetty executor is not of type QueuedThreadPool, but rather, " + executor.getClass().toString());
            }
        }
        ContextHandlerCollection collection = new ContextHandlerCollection();
        server.setHandler(collection);
```

Now add the SOAP endpoints

```
 Endpoint endpoint = Endpoint.create(retailPosIntegrationService);
                endpoint.publish(jettyServer.createContext(tsConfig.getRetailPOSServiceV2().getResource()));
```

Now add the REST service

```
 ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
                ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig().register(new VisaMobileIntegrationService(initializationSingletonBean));
                ServletContainer servletContainer = new ServletContainer(resourceConfig);
                context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new ServletContainer(resourceConfig(initializationSingletonBean))), "/*");
                server.setHandler(context);
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Seems we only have one port and cause a conflict.